# Passing a function as a class attribute of a Cython class

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to define a Cython class that accepts a function as one of the class attribute in the `__init__` function.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124049/is-there-any-type-for-function-in-cython) and tried the following

```
ctypedef int (*f_type)(int, int)

cdef class ClassWFunction:
    cdef f_type f

    def __init__( self, f_type f):
        self.f = f

    def doStuff(self, int x, int y):
        return self.f(x, y)

cdef int example_f(int a, int b):
    return a*b

classInstance = ClassWFunction(example_f)
classInstance.doStuff(2, 4)
```

which gives me the error:

```
Cannot convert 'int (int, int)' to Python object
```

I also read [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) from Cython's documentation and tried following that approach:

```
cdef class f_type:
    cpdef int evaluate(self, int a, int b) except *:
        return 0

cdef class ClassWFunctionV2:
    cdef f_type f

    def __init__( self, f_type f):
        self.f = f

    def doStuff(self, int a, int b):
        return self.f.evaluate(a, b)


cdef class example_f(f_type):
    cpdef int evaluate(self, int a, int b) except *:
        return a*b    


classInstance = ClassWFunctionV2(example_f)
classInstance.doStuff(3, 4)
```

which gives me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: Argument 'f' has incorrect type (expected _cython_magic_9f51dc40b83b28506fce9fb260a84618.f_type, got type)
```

Hopefully there's a way to make my first attempt work, since this second approach has a lot of boilerplate I don't quite understand!
Thanks for your time...

-------- Edit ----------

The point of writing the code this way is twofold:

1) to have a flexible way to change the `f` function when instantiating the class. 
2) The `f` function gets reused in many of the class methods, so I'd like to assign it to `self`

In my pure python code, I do stuff like

```
def f1(x): return x**2
def f2(x): return x**3

cl1 = ClassWFunction(f1)
cl2 = ClassWFunction(f2)
```

and then proceed to do things with those classes. However, I'm not 100% sure this is the best way to go around, so feel free to suggest a different approach.

-------- Edit2 ----------

As a less flexible but (hopefully!) easier alternative, I tried to hard-code the function onto the class. This would fit objective (2) above, even if it doesn't fit objective (1).

Consider (this also gives an error)

```
ctypedef int (*f_type)(int)
cdef class ClassWFunction:
    cdef f_type example_f
    cdef double x

    def __init__( self, int x):
        self.x = x
        # Tried with a python function too
        cdef int example_f(int z):
            return x*z
        self.example_f = example_f

    def doStuff(self, int x, int y):
        return self.example_f(x)*y

classInstance = ClassWFunction(3)
classInstance.doStuff(2, 4)
```

Comment: Do you want to pass in a Python function or a C function?  It's a little strange to be instantiating the class in Cython and passing a C function.  Usually your extension class would be instantiated by Python code that uses it.

Comment: @BrenBarn : in my code, the `example_f` is more or less critical, so I'd like to pass a cythonized function. I'd settle for passing a Python function though if the alternative is not possible.

Comment: How do you intend to use this code in Python-space?  Like, if you're just writing one static function in Cython, can't you just add it directly to the class?

Comment: I added an Edit to address your question -- I hope I understood it correctly. How would you add the function directly though?

Comment: In your original example, you pass a C function (created with `cdef`).  In your edit, you pass a Python function.  Are you saying you want to support both?  In general `cdef` functions are only accessible from C/Cython, so if you create a `cdef` function there would be no way to pass it in using Python code.  A comment on the question you linked suggests that if you want to allow passing in a Python function, you should use the `object` type.

Comment: @BrenBarn : OK, I see what you mean. I added an EDIT2 above to show my attempt to hard-code a function as an attribute. If you answer with a way to solve that, I'll accept it, since maybe my original attempt is just not possible in Cython. Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is why don't you write `example_f` as a method, just as you did with `do_stuff`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73269/discussion-between-cd98-and-brenbarn).