# How to type a function in function argument in cython

Tags: python, cython, static-typing

I have made a function for doing optimization in python (let's call it `optimizer`). It requires the function to be optimized (let's call it `objective`) as one of the function arguments. `objective` is a function that accepts a one-dimensional `np.ndarray` and return a `float` number (which is the same as `double` in C++?).

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124049/is-there-any-type-for-function-in-cython), but I'm not sure if it is actually the same problem as mine and when I use `ctypedef int (*f_type)(int, str)`, but I get the error `Cannot convert 'f_type' to Python object` during compilation. Does it only work for C functions? How do I type a python function?

Edit: How my code looks like:

```
cpdef optimizer(objective, int num_particle, int dim,
             np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] lower_bound,
             np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] upper_bound):

    cdef double min_value
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] positions = np.empty((num_particle,dim), dtype=np.double)
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] fitness = np.empty(num_particle, dtype=np.double)
    cdef int i, j

    # do lots of stuff not shown here
    # involve the following code:
    for i in range(num_particle):
        fitness[i] = objective(positions[i])

    return min_value
```

I want to know if it is possible to type `objective` to make the code run faster.

Comment: need more code to understand your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the error message

> `Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'f_type'`

which I think makes a lot more sense than the one you claim to get - you're trying to pass a Python object into the function. Please make sure that the error messages you report are the ones your code actually generates. Your description of the types that `objective` takes also does not match the code you show.

---

However, in general: no you cannot give your objective function a type specifier to speed it up. A generic Python callable carries a lot more information than a C function pointer (e.g. reference counts, details of any closure captured variables, etc).

A possible alternative approach would be to inherit from a `cdef class` with an appropriate `cdef` function, so you can at least get the appropriate performance in specific cases:

```
# an abstract function pointer class
cdef class FPtr:
    cdef double function(self,double[:] x) except? 0.0:
        # I'm assuming you might want to pass exceptions back to Python - use 0.0 to indicate that there might have been an error
        raise NotImplementedError()

# an example class that inherits from the abstract pointer type    
cdef class SumSq(FPtr):
    cdef double function(self,double[:] x) except? 0.0:
        cdef double sum=0.0
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
            sum += x[i]**2
        return sum

# an example class that just wraps a Python callable
# this will be no faster, but makes the code generically usable
cdef class PyFPtr(FPtr):
    cdef object f
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.f = f

    cdef double function(self,double[:] x) except? 0.0:
        return self.f(x) # will raise an exception if the types don't match

def example_function(FPtr my_callable):
    import numpy as np
    return my_callable.function(np.ones((10,)))
```

Using this `example_function(SumSq())` works as expected (and with Cython speed); `example_function(PyFPtr(lambda x: x[0]))` works as expected (without Cython speed in the callable); `example_function(PyFPtr(lambda x: "hello"))` gives a type error as expected.